# Periodically call a private function while a sound object is played

Tags: matlab, lambda

In Matlab App Designer I have an audioplayer object:

```
app.player = audioplayer(Time./max(abs(Time)), Fs);
```

The variable 'Time' contains the audio data and the variable 'Fs' is the sampling rate.
I now want to execute a function 'Playmov' every 0.1 seconds while the sound is played. I have tried the following:

```
app.player.TimerPeriod=0.1; % set the timer interval to 0.1 second
app.player.TimerFcn = @Playmov; % set the timer function to Playmov
```

The function is defined by:

```
methods (Access = private)
    function Playmov (app, event)
        disp('Hello World!')
        pause(1);
    end
end
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

> Warning: Error occurred while executing the listener callback for event Executing defined for class internal.IntervalTimer:
> Error using internal.Callback.execute (line 128)
> Undefined function 'Playmov' for input arguments of type 'audiovideo.internal.audioplayerDesktop'.
> In internal/IntervalTimer/onCustomEvent (line 154)
> In internal.IntervalTimer>@(source,data)obj.onCustomEvent(data.Type,data.Data) (line 115)
> In asyncio/Channel/onCustomEvent (line 477)
> In asyncio.Channel>@(source,data)obj.onCustomEvent(data.Type,data.Data) (line 409)

I have tried several modifications for the function-call, but I am a bit clueless what it should look like.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [this](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/346703-how-to-use-timer-callback-in-app-designer) forum post, I was able to solve the problem. I needed to change the function call to

```
app.player.TimerFcn = {@app.Playmov}; % set the timer function to Playmov
```

and the function definition accordingly to:

```
methods (Access = private)
    function Playmov (app, obj, event)
        disp('Hello World!')
        pause(1);
    end
end
```

So you need to specify 3 input arguments: 1st the handle to the app-object, because the function is a method of the app. 2nd the handle to the timer ('obj') and 3rd the handle for the event data for the timer event.